# How to expand (extract) information from highly nets JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested

I'm reading JSON file with Pandas and some of my rows contains things like these:

```
In[37]: df
Out[37]: 
66     {u'test_date': {u'$date': 1465513200000}, u'se...
81     {u'test_date': {u'$date': 1463958000000}, u'se...
155    {u'Nancy Index': 1, u'test_date': {u'$date': 1...
163    {u'Nancy Index': 2, u'test_date': {u'$date': 1...
213    {u'Nancy Index': 0, u'test_date': {u'$date': 1...
231    {u'Nancy Index': 0, u'test_date': {u'$date': 1...
```

Is there any nice Pandas function which can handle such nested data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jSon files are sometimes deeply nested. You can serialise these cell values again.

These serialiser is documented at
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html

Each jSon files is different; so you mind have to work yourself through the structure. There are a few good examples on Stack Overflow.